# How to delete an object in Parse from Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have my class name and friendName.

I dont have the objectId

What is the code to delete it in Parse from SWIFT?

In ObjC, it is something like:

```
PFObject *object = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"invFriend"
                                               objectId:@"abcd"];
[object deleteEventually];
```

How can i do that from swift without objectId?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the Swift equivalent code. Note that you must supply a valid columnName in the whereKey() method

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "invFriend")
query.whereKey("columnName", equalTo: "abcd")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    for object in objects {
        object.deleteEventually()
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, i dont have the objectId, i have the column  name. please see the edited Question

Comment: Thanks you. Works as Charm